# Where is it safest to store the jwt token in an HTTP environment?

Tags: cookies, jwt

Where is it safest to store the jwt token in an HTTP environment?

My web environment stores the jwt token as a cookie to the client.
However, I heard that storing the jwt token in a cookie is insecure.

After reading several articles, I heard that it is safe to use the `httpOnly` cookie.

But my web environment cannot use HTTPS.

I wonder where and where to store the jwt token in the HTTP environment.

Spring boot is issuing tokens.

Answer (score 0):

You will have a lot of problems due to the samesite cookie limitations when you use openid connect over HTTP.

some frameworks like ASP.NET Core store tokens in an ecrypted cookie, that is one approach.

Another approach is to use the BFF pattern as described in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEnbi4KClVw where the tokens are not directly stored in the client.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Debugging cookie problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/)

Answer (score 0):

When you are storing the access_token in a cookie, you are essentially creating your own session management system. Session management is a complex process that requires addressing various attack vectors to ensure security. Failure to mitigate these vectors is what renders this approach insecure.

The same principle applies to storing access tokens in the browser with localstorage or sessionstorage.

Recently, it has become widely accepted that it is not recommended to rely on a client-side application to obtain and store an access token. The rationale for this is that the client-side cannot be entrusted with a client_secret. By utilizing the client_secret, you can ensure that the access_token is not sent to a computer or person whom you do not trust with the token.

To answer your question:

- No, you should not use a cookie to store your access token

There are two reasons for this, with the most important reason being:

- A client-side application should not be entrusted with obtaining an access token, as it introduces an attack vector that hackers may exploit.
- It is advisable not to develop your own session management system. Instead, utilize existing session management systems.

Fore those reasons it is advisable to apply the [BFF Security Pattern](https://bff.gocloudnative.org/concepts/bff-security-pattern/). This same site describes how to apply it with their open source components (including sample code) [here](https://bff.gocloudnative.org/integration-manuals/quickstarts/auth0/quickstart/). The following options are a bit more complex i.m.o., but you should definitely have a look at [Duende.BFF](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/bff/), and [Azure Easy Auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-authentication-app-service).